# Div overlapping on one another

Tags: html, position

here's jsFiddle: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xeemez/4Zaqg/1/)

There are two `div`.One is in between the page content and another `div` is at the end of content(comes after scrolling).Now the problem is I wanted the first `div` to overlap second `div` but to do that I don't know how to do it.It will be a dynamic page so the page `height` keeps on changing so I can not `position` it with `absolute` and `top` or `bottom` keywords. How to do it ??
Note: the requirement is overlapping of orange on red.

Comment: What do you mean "overlap" ?  Do you want the orange div to lay right over the top of the red div?  Note: you use z-index to see who is on top.  Biggest numbers on top.  If you don't add z index, the first one listed will have a smaller z-index.

Comment: that wud be obvious to use z-index.My problem is postioning.how to position it as required.BTW I have added Z-index to the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in using jquery to determine the location of the first (orange) div than use those values to control the location of the second (red) div.  http://jsfiddle.net/4Zaqg/5/  Took me awhile to figure this one out.. the issue was the extra set of { } brackets.

Obviously I didn't touch the z-index, but instead chose to change the size of the divs slightly to verify what is going on...  OH, and please tell me this wasn't a homework assignment.

Add this script to your html file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var o = $("#orange").offset();
     $("#red").offset({left:o.left, top:o.top});
});
```

Comment: no it wasn't homework though I am starter in 'JavaScript'.So it was little complicated for me.But thanks it worked smoothely

Comment: one recommendation for you.  By doing the http://try.jquery.com tutorial I learned a heck of a lot about jquery but also a lot about CSS and javascript as well.  Until I did that tutorial, I never really understood what the crazy $() notation was...

Comment: I will surely give it a shot.Cheers ♥

Answer (score 0):

I found the way.we can have a CSS code like this to do this:

```
#orange{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:orange;
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    z-index:2;


}
#red{
     width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Fiddle :[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/xeemez/4Zaqg/4/)